# How to manage two stages in Heroku pipeline without GitHub integration

Tags: git, heroku, heroku-cli, heroku-pipelines

I have an app called `my-app` in heroku.

I transformed it into a pipeline with two stages (staging and prod). I don't want to use GitHub integration.

`my-app` is now in production.

I am using GitLab (which is free) and I fork `my-app` repo to a new branch called `feature-a`.

I want to add this fork to the staging stage of my pipeline. I want to be able to test the code in this stage before promoting to production.

When I add to the pipeline the app from the fork (or the merge) the Heroku CLI tells me that the app is already in pipeline, which is kind of true because one version is already in production.

My questions:

- How can I add to the staging stage of `my-app` pipeline a different version of the same app?
- Can stages have different environment variables (eg. staging will have dev keys & ids and production will have prod keys & ids)?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I add to the staging stage of my-app pipeline a different version of the same app?

If you want to add a branch of the same app to your pipeline you can manually create a new app, add it to your pipeline and then deploy your `feature-a` branch to that app for comparison.

> Can stages have different environment variables (eg. staging will have dev keys & ids and production will have prod keys & ids)?

Environment variables are app specific so you are able to specify different different keys for apps regardless of which pipeline lane they are in.

Comment: I guess App Reviews are only possible with GitHub integration, right ? Because we are not using it...

Comment: Ahh right, that is correct.  You'd have to manually create a new app to deploy your branch to.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching exactly the same thing that you asked, when in the Google results, I saw a link to a topic called "Managing Multiple Environments for an App" on Heroku documentation.

And for what I understoot, you want the same repository, in only one heroku app, but each release in a different stage.

Well, the documentation doesn't approach this kind of management, what we can understand that this is not possible.

But it approaches another kind of management, where you may have many branches in the same repository, and each branch are linked to a different app(I think this is the real problem).

Read the documentation on: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments

This kind of approach makes more sense in the corporate point of view, because, in a company where there's is a high maturity level in software development, you won't make any change directly on Master branch (Any mistake can become a huge mistake).

So what you can do to solve this problem if you're not using GitHub integration is: you create a specific app for your development branch, an app for your staging, and another one for your production(master) branch.

You deploy it separately, and after your tests, you merge your code to the other branch and deploy it.

Hope I have helped you!